# Почему Ansible при копировании папок, внутри которых еще папки, дает последним "пустые" права?

Tags: centos, ansible

Есть задача вида:

```
- name: Copying common web server configs
  tags:
      - services_prepare
  copy:
      src: "{{ item.src }}"
      dest: "{{ item.dest }}"
      directory_mode: yes
      owner: root
      group: root
      mode: 0644
  loop:
      - { src: "/root/repo_env/configs/common/exim/", dest: "/etc/exim/" }
      - { src: "/root/repo_env/configs/common/httpd/", dest: "/etc/httpd/" }
```

Суть ее в том, что она проходит то, что перечислено в `loop`, и выполняет каждый раз `copy` с параметрами, переданными из `loop` (`src`, `dest`). В папках, которые там указаны в `src`, есть подпапки. И вот эти подпапки всегда получают права `0001 (d----------x)` при их копировании. Но копируется все как надо.

Вопрос: Это глюк, или же просто надо как-то по особенному копировать вложенные папки? От `loop` избавлялся, дело не в этом.

Comment: Версия Ansible какая, укажите пожалуйста.

Comment: @Hellseher ansible 2.7.10, если я верно помню сервер, про который был тогда вопрос.